# Asp.net 2.0 routing

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms

I'm trying to implement a friendlyurl on asp.net 2.0 webform. I was to catch the id  on the target page by :

```
Page.RouteData.Values ["id"]
```

But i didn't find that.

Is there any alternative to Page.RouteData.Values on asp.net 2.0? 
Is there any way to implement routing on asp.net 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but you will have to implement some features to get ir working. It is not exactly a limitation, but there is no natively of the technology. Take a look at this link: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-complete-url-rewriting-solution-for-asp.net-2.0/

You will need to change some configs on the IIS to get it working fine.

Comment: sorry but the link shows the current question. can you please fix it?